# Can i make changes in the published version of aws lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, api-versioning

Lets consider i have a lambda function , i have two versions of it v1 and v2
and both version are published
If in any case i want to make code changes in v1 can i go directly to v1 and make code changes and publish the same version again?

Comment: I also noticed that almost all your questions have answers, yet not a single one accepted. Accepting good answers is not only a good practice, but it reduces number of duplicates and increases chances for your questions to be actually answered.

Comment: Definitely i am glad you answered my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly you can't. Published lambda versions are [immutable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-versions.html):

> You can change the function code and settings only on the **unpublished version** of a function.

If your version is already publish, any changes must be made to a new version.